# NestJS: User-Management handle different types of users

Tags: node.js, rest, express, backend, nestjs

I'm currently developing a REST user-service which should be able to store 3 types of users (administrator, tester, customer). My database schema is build on the "table per class" strategy. So I have a supertabel (users) which contains gerneral data like id, firstName, lastName, email, password and userType. For example the tester table has additional fields like rating and it's primary key is also a foreign key to the users table.

I've created a DTO for users in gerneral and extending DTOs corresponding to the tables, which are requested as payload in the routes. Is it possible to handle the different possible users in the same route (POST: "/users") or do I need to handle them individually with routes like "/users/admins", "/users/testers" and "/users/customers"?

**1. Approach**

Swagger is not able to process multiple interfaces.

```
  createUser(
    @Body() createUserDto: CreateAdminDto | CreateTesterDto | CreateCustomerDto
  ) {
    if (createUserDto.type === UserType.ADMIN) {
      //call userService to create admin -> cast DTO to adminInterface
      return 'admin';
    } else if (createUserDto.type === UserType.TESTER) {
      //call userService to create tester -> cast DTO to testerInterface
      return 'tester';
    } else if (createUserDto.type === UserType.CUSTOMER) {
      //call userService to create customer -> cast DTO to customerInterface
      return 'customer';
    }
  }
```

**2. Approach**
I've extended the CreateUserDto with a userData property, which contains the type specific data. With Swaggers `oneOf` you are able to show the different possibilities. Also it is easier to process. The root data gets into the user table and the nested userData gets into it's corresponding table.

```
import { UserType } from '../models/user';
import { CreateAdminDto } from './create-admin.dto';
import { CreateCustomerDto } from './create-customer.dto';
import { CreateTesterDto } from './create-tester.dto';

@ApiExtraModels(CreateAdminDto, CreateTesterDto, CreateCustomerDto)
export class CreateUserDtoNew {
  @ApiProperty()
  firstName: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  lastName: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  email: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  password: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  type: UserType;

  @ApiProperty({
    oneOf: [
      { $ref: getSchemaPath(CreateAdminDto) },
      { $ref: getSchemaPath(CreateTesterDto) },
      { $ref: getSchemaPath(CreateCustomerDto) }
    ]
  })
  userData: CreateCustomerDto | CreateTesterDto | CreateCustomerDto;
}
```

Comment: Keeping the `createUser` simple, I think your current approach is the way. I don't know if the swagger plugin handle this porperly tho.

Comment: @MicaelLevi swagger is not able to process this. I updated the question with another solution, which is maybe also better.

Comment: nice! How about the response shape?

Comment: I added to the `@ApiResponse({ type: User })` to the route. User is a TypeOrm entity which has `@ApiProperty()` decorators at the fields/columns.